# jQuery removing values from a comma separate list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given an input like:

```
<input type="test" value="3,4,9" />
```

What's the best way to remove a value like 9, 4 or 3, without having issues with the commas, I don't want this ending up:

```
value="3,4,"
value="3,,9"
value=",4,9"
```

Is there a clean way to get this done in JavaScript/jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could split your value into an array, then filter out values you do not want.

```
$("input[type='test']").val().split(",") // ["3","4","9"]
.filter(function(v){return !isNaN(parseInt(v))})    // filter out anything which is not 0 or more
```

Here is a less terse version which filters out anything which is not numeric

```
var array = $("input[type='test']").val().split(",");

// If you are dealing with numeric values then you will want
// to cast the string as a number
var numbers  = array.map(function(v){ return parseInt(v)});

// Remove anything which is not a number
var filtered = numbers.filter(function(v){ return !isNaN(v)});

// If you want to rejoin your values
var joined = filtered.join(",");
```

Finally change the value on the input

```
$("input[type='test']").val(joined);
```

Comment: nice, but in this case, 4 is a variable? how do you make 4 a js var?

Comment: `filter` takes a function which returns true or false.  If true the value is kept in the array, if false it is removed.  So adjust the filter function to your needs.  Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to PHP implode/explode functions

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
  var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
  this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
  return this.push.apply(this, rest);
};

var explode = value.split(',');
explode.remove(1);
var implode = explode.join(',');
```

Documentation:
[fce: Split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
[fce: Join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)
[fce: Array.remove](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/)

Comment: Interesting but I don't see how lines 1 and 3 are connected throughout your example?

Comment: That ends up breaking: ["3", undefined, "9"]
3,,9 outputed by         var explode = values_input.val().split(',');
         delete explode[1];
         var implode = explode.join(',');
         
         console.log(explode);
         console.log(implode);

Comment: @TheExit: position of number 4 (1st element has index 0)

Comment: using John Resig's remove function on Array's prototype, you can remove it better, but jQuery solution is way better :)

Answer (score 1):

No jQuery required :P

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //var subject = '3,4,9';
    //var subject = '3,,9';
    var subject = ',,4,9';

    var clean = Array();
    var i = 0;

    subject = subject.split(',');

    for (var a in subject)
    {
        if(subject[a].length)
        {
            clean[i] = subject[a];
            i++;
        }
    }

    document.write(clean.join(','));

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use pure javascript. Let say you want to take off only "4":

```
value = value.replace(/4,?/, '')
```

or "3" and "9":

```
value = value.replace(/([39],?)+/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this function will work for what you are trying to do: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
string.split(separator, limit)
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
array = string.split(separator);
```

to break a string into an array. then use this to join after manipulations.

```
string = array.join(separator);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ary = value.split(',');
ary.splice(indexOfItemToRemove,1)
var result = ary.join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed in another post:

[remove value from comma separated values string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306164/remove-value-from-comma-separated-values-string)

```
var removeValue = function(list, value, separator) {
   separator = separator || ",";
   var values = list.split(",");
   for(var i = 0 ; i < values.length ; i++) {
      if(values[i] == value) {
         values.splice(i, 1);
         return values.join(",");
      }
   }
   return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
function removeComma(x) {
    var str = '';
    var subs = '';

    for(i=1; i<=x.length; i++) {
        subs = x.substring(i-1, i).trim();

        if(subs !== ',') {
            str = str+subs;
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```