# Remove a value in a string with a wildcard using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying  to return a comma separated string without the items that end in 'non'.

Source:

```
id = '2345,45678,3333non,489,2333non';
```

Expected Result:

```
id = '2345,45678,489';
```

I'm using code that I found here: 
[remove value from comma separated values string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306164/remove-value-from-comma-separated-values-string)

```
var removeValue = function(list, value, separator) {
  separator = separator || ",";
  var values = list.split(separator);
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i] == value) {
      values.splice(i, 1);
      return values.join(separator);
    }
  }
  return list;
}
```

Is there a way to make the line `(values[i] ==  value)` use a wildcard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `/[^,]*non,|,[^,]*non/g`:

```js
id = '2345,45678,3333non,489,2333non';

console.log(
  id.replace(/[^,]*non,|,[^,]*non/g, '')
)
```

---

As a function:

```js
id = '2345,45678,3333non,489,2333non';

removeItem = function(s, ends) {
  pat = new RegExp(`[^,]*${ends},|,[^,]*${ends}`, 'g')
  return s.replace(pat, '')
}

console.log(removeItem(id, 'non'))
```

Comment: love the single line of  id.replace(/[^,]*non,|,[^,]*non/g, '')  How do I change the line to get only the non's now that you made it so easy for me.  I don't use RegEx very much

Comment: Your regex could get a bit shorter `,?\d+non`

Comment: A little clunky, but `id.replace(/([^,]*non,|,[^,]*non)|([^,]*,|,[^,]*)/g, '$1')` should do. @user1314159

Comment: @revo That would leave a comma at the beginning of string, if the string starts with a pattern, e.g. `123non,123,234`.

Comment: Fantastic- leading comma is not a problem  THANK YOU

Comment: I hate to ask but If I changed my ID string to '2345,45678,NON333,489,NON2333'  What would the  Regex be for the id.replace(/[^,]*non,|,[^,]*non/g, '')  I change the spot for the id.replace(/[^,]non*,|,[^,]non*/g, '')  but that didn't work.  Thanks

Comment: For that case you can use `id.replace(/non[^,]*,|,non[^,]*/gi, '')`. `[^,]*` matches a non comma pattern so they need to be moved together.

Comment: Thank you very much and this works great but misses the last NON if it is the last value.  I can add a comma at the end and it will catch it and then remove the comma if need be.  What are your thoughts- I do appreciate your input

Answer (score 3):

You can also get that result without using `regex` like this:

```js
var id = '2345,45678,3333non,489,2333non';  
var resArray = id.split(',').filter((item) => item.indexOf('non') === -1);
var resString = resArray.toString();
console.log(resString);
```

If you do not want to use arrow funtion:

```js
var id = '2345,45678,3333non,489,2333non';  
var resArray = id.split(',').filter(function(item) {
   return item.indexOf('non') === -1;
});
var resString = resArray.toString();
console.log(resString);
```

Comment: @OP Note that Arrow Functions are not supported in IE and semi-supported in Edge. [**Arrow Function - Browser Compatibility**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this. Just split on `,` and filter the array for all elements that don't end in `non`.

```js
var id = '2345,45678,3333non,489,2333non'
console.log(id.split(',').filter(x => !x.endsWith('non')).join(','))
```

Thanks to [Nope](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448144/nope) for pointing out that  `endsWith()` will not work in IE. To get around this issue, see [Mozilla's Polyfill for `endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith#Polyfill) or [JavaScript endsWith is not working in IEv10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544376/javascript-endswith-is-not-working-in-iev10/37545037).